# Javascript redirect after POST, Submit analog

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I dont have form on page, on button click i need go to seconpage.asp and also post requeried POST data

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Will be good if it load Post url after Post like full Submit analog, But it not do the redirect to this page only if there are form on page and button submit.
If redirect on success, then Page Load it defaults whithout Post data

So if I send POST

```
$.ajax({
  type: "seconpage.asp",
  url: url,
  data: "Hello It Works",
  success: function(){
    location.href="seconpage.asp";
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Then loads `seconpage.asp` I need to get "Hello It Works" but I get nothing
As `seconpage.asp` contains only

```
<%=Request.Form%>
```

So this is not Submit analog, because Submit load page with Post data, instead of redirect load new page without Post data

Comment: Use window.location.href="seconpage.asp" after the Ajax POST success.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(){
      location.href="target-page.asp";
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Remember if you are using a type-submit button, you have to prevent default behaviour or just return false:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // you can use this
    $.ajax({ /*...*/ });
    return false; // or this
});
```

---

**Edit**:

After see your post update I see the problem. To pass the data you need to pass it through a variable:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: { mydata: "Hello It Works" },
  success: function(){
      location.href="target-page.asp";
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Then, in your controller or server-side method, manage the data received.

[Check jQuery Ajax Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more information about ajax options and how to proceed.

Comment: As I sad  `location.href="target-page.asp";` Loads page defaults whithout Post data

Comment: Maybe we need to see all your relevant code, because if you put the `location.href` line in the ajax success function, it will fire **after** post data by ajax (usually desired).

Comment: Look please Updated question

Comment: Maybe using ajax `processData` option and setting it to false you can send an string directly. It is commonly used to send `DOMDocument` or other **non-processed** data. I have to say I didn't use it never, so I am not sure how it works or if it is valid here.